# Angular UI not updating after data changes

Tags: mean-stack, angular7

Im new to the MEAN stack and having trouble with getting data changes to be refreshed in the UI. I know the data is getting saved properly in MongoDB, and also retrieved, because when I create a Todo item and I refresh the page, the newly added Todo item appears in the Todo List. The problem is that it isnt happening dynamically.

I've tried a number of different things including NgZone and ChangeDetectorRef to detect changes, not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Let me know if any more info is needed.. thank you!

The Todo List component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../todo.model';
import { TodoService } from '../../todo.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-todo-list',
templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./todo-list.component.scss'],
providers: [TodoService]
})
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() todos: Todo[] = [];

constructor(private _todoService: TodoService, private zone: NgZone){}

getTodos() {
    console.log('todo list - get todos');
    this._todoService.getTodos()
        .subscribe(resTodoData => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.todos = resTodoData;
            });
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('todo list - init');
    this.getTodos();
}
}
```

Service Component:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from 
'@angular/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Todo } from './todos/todo.model';

 @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
  })
 export class TodoService {

// these were configured in express server
private _getUrl = "/api/todos";
private _postUrl = "/api/todo";

constructor(private _http: Http, private zone: NgZone) { }

getTodos() {

    let json = this._http.get(this._getUrl)
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
    return json;    
}

addTodo(todo: Todo) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this._postUrl, JSON.stringify(todo), 
               options)
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
  }
}
```

Comment: you need a websocket (like socket.io) to make a two way communication with your backend server.

Comment: Thanks for responding :) could you elaborate a bit more? as I understand it the problem is not with the back end, because the data appears on the UI after refreshing. I think the issue is how to get the UI to render the updated data without having to refresh the page. But i am open to all suggestions :)

Comment: It appears because on refresh component rebuilds itself and calls `this.getTodos();` again

Comment: Ok thanks. Im still struggling a bit.. from what I can gather it also relates to Observable? I'll keep working on it, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well, it is an Observable :) But you wont get live data update if you wont use websocket

Comment: I found this resource: https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/display-real-time-data-in-angular/amp/ which described 1.Observables with async and 2.Web Sockets. I tried the first one, and it worked :) so i havent tried with web sockets yet but maybe ill do it later as an experiment. One issue with the Observables/async option seems to be that it constantly needs to check at intervals for changes.. im not sure that its economical. If you have thoughts about it, Id be happy to hear. Thanks again!

Comment: I did not dare to recommend setInterval() :) But if that just one or two places you need this, maybe its ok... But if interval is 1 sec. and GET leasts longer - you will never get results

Comment: Ah I thought it might be something like that :) good to know, thanks. Well hopefully at some point I can try out your other suggestion and see how it works.